# iTunesConnect primary language not found

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-app

I want to develop an iPhone App. and I paid Apple for the developer's license which is $99/year and I logged in to iTunesConnect.

But when the portal ask me to select my language (language for application description) (primary language) I cannot find my language!

How can i add the language that I required in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry..
Because this is a first time i use iTunesConnect i think the primary language for the description for application
But as i see the primary languge is to determine the languge that the pages will apper 
i.e the pages for next steps will appear in the language that will specify from this list.

:)

Comment: This is a huge problem.   The itunes process should make it very clear that the very first primary language selection is for the *account* and *unchangeable*, it's not just for the application.

Answer (score 2):

I've made the mistake to choose german as the primary language in my case. I thought choosing german iTunes connect would guide me with german language through the setup process.
Now where my app is released I'm facing the problem that the app description always shows the german description in countries my app is not localized for (it's just german and english). So you should be aware of which language you choose as primary language.

Comment: ohhhh, umm..But really i need another language that not listed in the languages list (like Arabic or herbro) how can i add the language ????